# Selenium : headless browser not switching windows in docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, headless

`I am trying to run my selenium tests in docker container/AWS Fargate, i have the below chrome options configured.

```
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless=new");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-application-cache");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

I am packaging everything in to a jar file and running them.

My tests run fine when I run them in local with normal mode and headless mode. When I run the same tests in docker container I am not able to switch to the window tabs.

NOTE : I am able to switch to windows in headless mode in my local system, the issue is only in the container. Also, my other tests run fine in container, it is only the windows switch that doesn't work.

Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu

#version of chrome
ENV CHROME_VERSION 116.0.5845.140
ENV EDGE_VERSION 116.0.1938.54

# Workspace
WORKDIR /usr/share/SeleniumFrameworkPoc

#installing dependency and updating pre-existing libs
RUN echo "Updating Packages.";apt-get update -y  >>  update.log
RUN echo "Installing Jdk..";apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk -y >> java.log
RUN echo "Installing wget...";apt-get install wget -y >> wget.log
RUN echo "Installing unzip....";apt-get install unzip -y >> unzip.log

#installing Chrome
RUN wget -q http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb --no-verbose
RUN apt-get install ./google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb -y >> chrome.log

#installing edge
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/pool/main/m/microsoft-edge-stable/microsoft-edge-stable_${EDGE_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb --no-verbose
RUN apt-get install ./microsoft-edge-stable_${EDGE_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb -y

#installing Chromedriver and moving it to /usr/bin
#RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${CHROME_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip --no-verbose
#RUN unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
#RUN mv  -v chromedriver /usr/bin

#checking and removing the setup files
RUN ls
RUN rm google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb;#rm chromedriver_linux64.zip;
RUN rm *.log
RUN echo "removal check";ls
RUN apt-get clean -y

#verifying Versions
HEALTHCHECK CMD java -version;google-chrome --version || exit 1

# ADD .jar under target from host(local) into this image
ADD target/ECommSeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar                   ECommSeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
#ADD target/SeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar       SeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
#ADD target/libs                                                            libs
#ADD src/test/resources                                                      src/test/resources

# ADD testng suite files
#ADD pcc-testng.xml                                                             pcc-testng.xml

# ADD health check script
#ADD healthcheck.sh                         healthcheck.sh
#RUN dos2unix healthcheck.sh

#TAGS
ENTRYPOINT java -Dbrowser=$BROWSER -jar ECommSeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar -testjar ECommSeleniumFramework-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar -xmlpathinjar $MODULE
```

Any solution which will help me in running the window switch tests in docker container`